# Get a single phone number from contacts Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

Hi I am trying to get a single phone number from the contact list . I have found code which gets me the whole contact list telephone numbers, all I want is the telephone number for the item clicked. Any Help would be gratefully appreciated . Thanks ..

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent,CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?",new String[] { id }, null);

                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), phoneNo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: which contact? random? or first one?

Comment: the contact which is clicked after the contact list is opened .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in your contacts list and click a Contact, you are going to get the Result of your `Intent.ACTION_PICK` intent.

So, to handle the result, you have to override `onActivityResult()` method.

You receive the lookup URI of your contact in the data `Intent` object returned by `onActivityResult()`.

So, all you have to do is this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT){
        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor contentCursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null,null, null);

            if(contentCursor.moveToFirst()){
                String id = contentCursor.getString(contentCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                String hasPhone =
                        contentCursor.getString(contentCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
                {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                    String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.i("phoneNUmber", "The phone number is "+ contactNumber);

                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to do whatever you want with the value on `contactNumber`.

Hope to have help you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all add this line in AndroidManifest.xml to take permission from user.

Mobile User also need to allow this permission.it can be done manually from settings

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

now in button Click listener write this code.

```
        contactsButtton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent,1);

            }
        });
```

Now from the outside of the onCreate() function. you have to override the onActivityResult() function.
similar to this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 1 :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Cursor cur = cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (cur.getCount() > 0) {// thats mean some resutl has been found
                    if(cur.moveToNext()) {
                        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Log.e("Names", name);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                        {
                            // Query phone here. Covered next
                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                Log.e("Number", phoneNumber);
                            }
                            phones.close();
                        }

                    }
                }
                cur.close();
            }
            break;
    }

}
```